# Парсинг даты не работает на боевом сервере

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

Передаем в адресной строке приложению такие данные:

http://server/controllerName/start=01.05.2018;end=10.05.2018

На стороне сервера в одном из сервисов парсим дату таким вот методом:

```
private DateTime ConvertDateFromString(string date) {
    CultureInfo fromCulture = new CultureInfo("de-de");

    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, 
        fromCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern, 
        fromCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, 
        out DateTime tryParseDateTime)) {

        return tryParseDateTime;
    }

    throw new FormatException($"Дата указана в не поддерживаемом формате: {date}. Поддерживаемый формат DD.MM.YYYY");
}
```

В случае если запросе делаем на локальной машине то все работает ок, но когда программу запускаем в контейнере, то парсинг не удается и мы попадаем в участок с `FormatException`.

В чем может быть беда?

**UPDATED:**
Разработка ведется на винде а сервер на линуксе.
Сейчас почитал что в линуксе может по другому называться культура Германии, видимо проблема в этом.

Comment: попробуй "de_DE"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще, конечно, проблема скорее всего именно в названии формата `de-de`, вместо `de-DE`, однако .dotnet core кросс-платформенный и таких проблем быть не должно. Но как вариант:

```
string format = "dd.MM.yyyy";
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTime, 
                       format, 
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                       DateTimeStyles.None, 
                       out dt);
```

Comment: `InvariantCulture` тоже не всегда верно указывать, если например нужно учитывать часовой пояс.

Comment: @ГеннадийП так ведь там строка уже приходит, разницы то не должно быть

Comment: Ну, например данные приходят из одного часового пояса в местном формате, а сервер находится в другом часовом поясе. По идее правильней переводить передаваемые данные в `InvariantCulture` тогда меньше хлопот будет.

Comment: @ГеннадийП ну да)

Comment: Если уж на то пошло, то, чтобы правильно работать с часовыми поясами, нужно всегда использовать `DateTimeOffset` (и навсегда забыть о `DateTime`). См. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14268167/5045688